# Python Text adventure shop

Tags: python

I defined a shop in my text adventure python game. I defined some things like

```
player_money = 0
```

and then I made a shop define

```
def shop(player_money,player_inventory):
    for choice in shope:
        print(choice)
    shop_choice = input()
    if shop_choice == 'ㄱ':
        for choice2 in level_1to10_shop:
            print(choice2)
        buying = input()
        if buying == '1':
            if player_money >= wood_shield_value:
                print(str(wood_shield) + '을 ' + str(wood_shield_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(wood_shield)
                player_money -= wood_shield_value
                
            elif player_money < wood_shield_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '2':
            if player_money >= wood_armor_value:
                print(str(wood_armor) + '을 ' + str(wood_armor_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(wood_armor)
                player_money -= wood_armor_value
            elif player_money < wood_armor_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '3':
            if player_money >= wood_sword_value:
                print('bought' + str(wood_sword) + 'for' + str(wood_sword_value))
                player_inventory.append(wood_sword)
                player_money -= wood_sword_value
            elif player_money < wood_sword_value:
                print('need more money')

        else:
            print('choose between 1,2,3 please')
```

but then when I print how much money I have left after I buy something, The money didn't go down at all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um6zR.png)

above is how much money I had before and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzQ8J.png)

this is when i buy it. it means 'bought wooden shield for 5 gold'

and then if i check my balance again it says
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJoPf.png)

it didnt go down at all

My full code is below

```
import sys
import time
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

player_money = 5
player_exp = 0
player_max_exp = 100
player_attack_dmg = 10
player_health = 100
player_defence = 5
player_agility = 5
player_intelligence = 5
player_mana = 50
player_luck = 1

player_stat = ['피 : ' + str(player_health), '공격력 : ' + str(player_attack_dmg), '방어력 : ' + str(player_defence), '속도 : ' + str(player_agility), '마나 : ' + str(player_mana), '지능 : ' + str(player_intelligence), '운 : ' + str(player_luck)]
player_inventory = []

wood_sword = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '3.) 나무 칼'
wood_sword_value = 5

wood_armor = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '2.) 나무 갑옷'
wood_armor_value = 5

wood_shield = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '1.) 나무 방패'
wood_shield_value = 5

stone_sword = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '3.) 돌 검'
stone_sword_value = 100

stone_armor = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '2.) 돌 갑옷'
stone_armor_value = 100

stone_shield = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '1.) 돌 방패'
stone_shield_value = 100

steel_sword = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '3.) 철 칼'
steel_sword_value = 1000

steel_armor = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '2.) 철 갑옷'
steel_armor_value = 1000

steel_shield = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '1.) 철 방패'
steel_shield_value = 1000

diamond_sword = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '3.) 다이아 칼'
diamond_sword_value = 10000

diamond_armor = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '2.) 다이아 갑옷'
diamond_armor_value = 10000

diamond_shield = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '1.) 다이아 방패'
diamond_shield_value = 10000

legend_sword = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '3.) 래전드 칼'
legend_sword_value = 100000

legend_armor = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '2.) 래전드 갑옷'
legend_armor_value = 100000

legend_shield = Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + '1.) 래전드 방패'
legend_shield_value = 100000


level_1to10_shop = [wood_shield + '가치 : ' + str(wood_shield_value), wood_armor + '가치 : ' + str(wood_armor_value), wood_sword + '가치 : ' + str(wood_sword_value)]
level_11to20_shop = [stone_shield + '가치 : ' + str(stone_shield_value), stone_armor + '가치 : ' + str(stone_armor_value), stone_sword + '가치 : ' + str(stone_sword_value)]
level_21to30_shop = [steel_shield + '가치 : ' + str(steel_shield_value), steel_armor + '가치 : ' + str(steel_armor_value), steel_sword + '가치 : ' + str(steel_sword_value)]
level_31to50_shop = [diamond_shield + '가치 : ' + str(diamond_shield_value), diamond_armor + '가치 : ' + str(diamond_armor_value), diamond_sword + '가치 : ' + str(diamond_sword_value)]
above_50_shop = [legend_shield + '가치 : ' + str(legend_shield_value), legend_armor + '가치 : ' + str(legend_armor_value), legend_sword + '가치 : ' + str(legend_sword_value)]

shope = ['ㄱ : 레밸 1-10 상점(F)', 'ㄴ : 레밸 11-20 상정(C)', 'ㄷ : 레밸 21 - 30 상점(B)', 'ㄹ : 레밸 31 - 50 상점(A)', 'ㅁ : 레밸 50 이상 상점 (SS)']

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

def print_normal(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)

def print_fast(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)

def check_age(player_age):
    if player_age < 13:
        print_normal('13세 미만 이어서 이 게임을 못합니다')
    elif player_age >= 13:
        pass

def check_race(player_race):
    if player_race == '인간' or player_race == '도마뱀' or player_race == '엘프' or player_race == '오크':
        pass
    else:
        print('음.. 오타치신거 같은데 인간, 도마뱀, 엘프, 오크 중 하나만;;')
        exit()   

def command_list():
    print(Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.YELLOW + '[%프로필] 레벨, 종족, 이름, 나이, 돈 등등을 보여줌')
    print('[%지도] 갈수 있는곳들을 보여줌')
    print('[%리스트] 명령어 리스트')
    print('[%인벤토리] 아이탬 목록')
    print('[%상점] 상점')
    print('[%도박] 도박장')
    print('[%미션] 퀘스트')
    print('[%모험] 모험을 떠남 (그 장소에서)')
    print('[%스킬] 스킬 목록')

def profile():
    print(Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.GREEN + '소유한 돈 : ' + str(player_money))
    print('이름 : ' + player_name)
    print('나이 : ' + str(player_age))
    print('종족 : ' + str(player_race))
    print('스탯 : ')
    for stat in player_stat:
        print(stat)

def inventory():
    for item in player_inventory:
        print(item)

def shop(player_money,player_inventory):
    for choice in shope:
        print(choice)
    shop_choice = input()
    if shop_choice == 'ㄱ':
        for choice2 in level_1to10_shop:
            print(choice2)
        buying = input()
        if buying == '1':
            if player_money >= wood_shield_value:
                print(str(wood_shield) + '을 ' + str(wood_shield_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(wood_shield)
                player_money -= wood_shield_value
                
            elif player_money < wood_shield_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '2':
            if player_money >= wood_armor_value:
                print(str(wood_armor) + '을 ' + str(wood_armor_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(wood_armor)
                player_money -= wood_armor_value
            elif player_money < wood_armor_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '3':
            if player_money >= wood_sword_value:
                print(str(wood_sword) + '을 ' + str(wood_sword_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(wood_sword)
                player_money -= wood_sword_value
            elif player_money < wood_sword_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        else:
            print('음 1,2,3 중에 선택해 주세요')

    elif shop_choice == 'ㄴ':
        for choice3 in level_11to20_shop:
            print(choice3)
        buying = input()
        if buying == '1':
            if player_money >= stone_shield_value:
                print(str(stone_shield) + '을 ' + str(stone_shield_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(stone_shield)
                player_money -= stone_shield_value
            elif player_money < stone_shield_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '2':
            if player_money >= stone_armor_value:
                print(str(stone_armor) + '을 ' + str(stone_armor_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(stone_armor)
                player_money -= stone_armor_value
            elif player_money < stone_armor_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '3':
            if player_money >= stone_sword_value:
                print(str(stone_sword) + '을 ' + str(stone_sword_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(stone_sword)
                player_money -= stone_sword_value
            elif player_money < stone_sword_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        else:
            print('음 1,2,3 중에 선택해 주세요')

    elif shop_choice == 'ㄷ':
        for choice4 in level_21to30_shop:
            print(choice4)
        buying = input()
        if buying == '1':
            if player_money >= steel_shield_value:
                print(str(steel_shield) + '을 ' + str(steel_shield_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(steel_shield)
                player_money -= steel_shield_value
            elif player_money < steel_shield_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '2':
            if player_money >= steel_armor_value:
                print(str(steel_armor) + '을 ' + str(steel_armor_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(steel_armor)
                player_money -= steel_armor_value
            elif player_money < steel_armor_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '3':
            if player_money >= steel_sword_value:
                print(str(steel_sword) + '을 ' + str(steel_sword_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(steel_sword)
                player_money -= steel_sword_value
            elif player_money < steel_sword_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        else:
            print('음 1,2,3 중에 선택해 주세요')

    elif shop_choice == 'ㄹ':
        for choice5 in level_31to50_shop:
            print(choice5)
        buying = input()
        if buying == '1':
            if player_money >= diamond_shield_value:
                print(str(diamond_shield) + '을 ' + str(diamond_shield_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(diamond_shield)
                player_money -= diamond_shield_value
            elif player_money < diamond_shield_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '2':
            if player_money >= diamond_armor_value:
                print(str(diamond_armor) + '을 ' + str(diamond_armor_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(diamond_armor)
                player_money -= diamond_armor_value
            elif player_money < diamond_armor_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '3':
            if player_money >= diamond_sword_value:
                print(str(diamond_sword) + '을 ' + str(diamond_sword_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(diamond_sword)
                player_money -= diamond_sword_value
            elif player_money < diamond_sword_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        else:
            print('음 1,2,3 중에 선택해 주세요')

    elif shop_choice == 'ㅁ':
        for choice6 in above_50_shop:
            print(choice6)
        buying = input()
        if buying == '1':
            if player_money >= legend_shield_value:
                print(str(legend_shield) + '을 ' + str(legend_shield_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(legend_shield)
                player_money -= legend_shield_value
            elif player_money < legend_shield_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '2':
            if player_money >= legend_armor_value:
                print(str(legend_armor) + '을 ' + str(legend_armor_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(legend_armor)
                player_money -= legend_armor_value
            elif player_money < legend_armor_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        elif buying == '3':
            if player_money >= legend_sword_value:
                print(str(legend_sword) + '을 ' + str(legend_sword_value) +' 주고 샀음니다')
                player_inventory.append(legend_sword)
                player_money -= legend_sword_value
            elif player_money < legend_sword_value:
                print('돈 부족 ㅠ')

        else:
            print('음 1,2,3 중에 선택해 주세요')



player_name = str(input(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + '이름을 입력하세요 : '))
player_age = int(input('나이를 입력하세요 : '))
check_age(player_age)
print('종족 선택하십시오 :')
print(Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.RED + '인간' + Style.RESET_ALL + '] ' + Fore.RED + '인간은 가장 밸런스 된 인종')
print(Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.GREEN + '도마뱀' + Style.RESET_ALL + '] ' + Fore.GREEN + '도마뱀은 속도가 높고, 힘이 약함')
print(Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.YELLOW + '엘프' + Style.RESET_ALL + '] ' + Fore.YELLOW + '엘프는 활을 잘쏘고 명중률이 높다')
player_race = str(input(Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX + '오크' + Style.RESET_ALL + ']' + Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX + ' 오크는 힘이 넘치고 느리다' + Style.RESET_ALL +'\n'))
#player_race = str(input('종족 선택하십시오 :\n' + Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.RED + '인간' + Style.RESET_ALL + '] ' + Fore.RED + '인간은 가장 밸런스 된 인종\n' + Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.GREEN + '도마뱀' + Style.RESET_ALL + '] ' + Fore.GREEN + '도마뱀은 속도가 높고, 힘이 약함\n' + Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.YELLOW + '엘프' + Style.RESET_ALL + '] ' + Fore.YELLOW + '엘프는 활을 잘쏘고 명중률이 높다\n' + Style.RESET_ALL + '[' + Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX + '오크' + Style.RESET_ALL + ']' + Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX + ' 오크는 힘이 넘치고 느리다' + Style.RESET_ALL +'\n'))
check_race(player_race)
while True:
    print_normal(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + '%리스트 라고 치면 명령어들이 뜸\n')
    chat = input()

    if chat == '%리스트':
        command_list()

    elif chat == '%프로필':
        profile()

    elif chat == '%인벤토리':   
        inventory()

    elif chat == '%상점':
        shop(player_money, player_inventory)

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code which prints `player_money`, how would you know if it went down or not?

Comment: thats only part of my code

Comment: So edit your question to make it a [mcve].

Comment: done! it has korean letters tho

Comment: A **minimal** reproducible is the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. There is definitely a lot of code in your question which is unrelated to the issue you are asking about. The onus is on you to do this work, not on the volunteers who answer questions here.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
Your posted code does not run.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?
Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player_money` is a local variable in function `shop()`. While it is modified within that function, those changes do not modify the variable passed to the function. For example:

```
x = 10

def f(x):
    print(x)
    x += 10
    print(x)

print(x)
f(x)
print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
10
10
20
10
```

which demonstrates that the variable is changed locally, but not globally.

You can return the updated `player_money` at the end of the function and then call it like this:

```
player_money = shop(player_money, player_inventory)
```

Alternatively, you could make the variable global using a [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) statement inside the function.

A better design would be to encapsulate the (many) player attributes into a class and pass an instance of that class to the various functions that could modify any of the player's attributes.

Comment: then how do i fix it, i tried to do like 'return player_money -= wooden_armor_cost' but there was a error and i dont know how

Comment: You already have an update for the player_money within the function e.g. 'player_money -= wood_sword_value'. So at the end, you can simply 'return player_money'. But since you also updated the inventory you want to call the function with 'player_money, player_inventory = shop(player_money, player_inventory)' and return from the function with 'return player_money, player_inventory'. That way your money and inventory get updated with the returned values from the shop function.

Comment: @Pines: inventory is a list so it is mutable. Changes made to the items of that list will be visible outside the function. Although it could be, the list it doesn't need to be returned from the function.